# My PHP file is working but has bits of code showing

Tags: php, zend-framework2

So here is the code that I input for my .php file.

```
<html> 
    <head>  
        <title>PHP Test</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the result that I am seeing on my end is:

Hello World

'; ?>

I am using Netbeans to SFTP the file to my university's server and it looks the same in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer. I am using the zend 2 framwork with the zend skeleton installed and XAMPP for the stack. I also have PHP 5.5 installed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd guess isn't not working at all, i.e. the file isn't being processed by PHP. Check the view source, do you see the rest of the code?

Comment: i think there is an ';?> in the layout file if you are using layouts. Please share your controller action code here.

Comment: When I checked the view source I could see everything that I typed including the php statement.

Comment: @Jasbir Singh Sohanpal
I think this is my controller?
`<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}`

Comment: @user3044394 Then your server isn't set up correctly by the sounds of it.

Comment: I didn't set up the server. It's the University of Pittsburgh's server. I'm just pushing files to it.

Comment: Then it might be time to talk to the Unversity I.T. staff.

Comment: I've been speaking with some of my other classmates and they were able to set it up on their end. I think it is an issue on my end

Comment: Just checking. But you are accessing it via HTTP and not FTP in your browser, right?

Comment: I am using both:
http://localhost:8080/MyProject/helloworld.php 
and 
http://studentprojects.sis.pitt.edu/fall2015/srp63/helloworld.php

both have the same result

Comment: if you click that second link you can see my php file. I had to edit it because initially I typed the wrong address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem. The issue was with XAMPP. I don't know what it was, but I did a complete reinstall of XAMPP - then tried again and it works perfectly now. Thank you everyone for your help. I must have installed the software wrong or something

Answer (score 1):

The code you included in your question is not the same as the code in the URL you gave in the comments. In your actual code you have:

```
<?
echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
```

Note the use of `<?` (the [PHP short tag](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)) rather than `<?php`. It's likely that your server is not configured to use PHP short tags (this is something that is disabled by default).

Switch this to `<?php` (like the code in your question) and assuming your server is configured correctly it should work fine.

Comment: I just uploaded to: http://studentprojects.sis.pitt.edu/fall2015/srp63/helloworld.php
I changed the tag back to <?php and it didn't work. I actually just change it to a short tag a few mins ago  to see if it would work as a test.

Comment: In that case what was said in the comments is correct - the Uni server either doesn't support PHP or is not configured correctly. Either way you'll need to talk to your Uni IT staff.

Comment: It sounds like you have two separate problems then, as the issue doesn't appear to be with your code. It's quite possible for PHP to be enabled on in some folders and not others, which may be the case for your uni host, but I'd focus on fixing localhost first.